# When do we add Ye'aleh V'yaboh?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, mistakes, shulchan-aruch, chagim-holidays

*According to Shulchan Aruch, (please cite Saeef and Siman so I can read further):*

What are all the days we add Ye'aleh V'yaboh?

What happens if we forget to say it?

Comment: Comprehensive list with Halchos and sources: http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Yaaleh_VeYavo